# Cracking the Coding Interview 5th Ed., 9.10

Tags: java, oop, recursion, dynamic-programming

In Cracking the Coding Interview (5th edition), the following question is presented:

*You have a stack of n boxes with widths w(i), h(i), and d(i). The boxes cannot be rotated and can only be stacked on top of one another if each box in the stack is strictly larger than the box above it in width, height, and depth. Implement a method to build the tallest stack possible, where the height of a stack is the sum of the heights of each box.*

I came up with the following recursive solution that does not involve any Dynamic Programming:

```
 public static List<Box> stackBoxes(List<Box> boxes){
    if(boxes.size() <= 1){
        return boxes;
    }

    List<Box> temp = new ArrayList<Box>();
    temp = stackBoxes(boxes.subList(1, boxes.size()));
    Box currentBox = new Box(0, 0, 0);
    currentBox = boxes.get(0);

    for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++){
        Box nextBox = new Box(0,0,0);
        nextBox = temp.get(i);
        if(nextBox.x >= currentBox.x && nextBox.y >= currentBox.y 
                && nextBox.z >= currentBox.z){

            List<Box> half1 = new ArrayList<Box>(temp.subList(0, i));
            half1.add(currentBox);

            List<Box> half2 = new ArrayList<Box>(temp.subList(i,  
            temp.size()));

            half1.addAll(half2);
            return half1;
        }
    }

    List<Box> newStack = new ArrayList<Box>();
    newStack.addAll(temp);
    newStack.add(currentBox);
    return newStack;

}
```

Box class (x-width, y-height, z-depth):

```
public class Box {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;

    public Box(int x, int y, int z){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

To me it seems there will always only be one optimal stacking for the boxes, since any box at any given location in the stack will be either equal to or greater than the ones above it in width, height, and depth. So essentially, the optimal stacking would be an ordered list where each box is <= the one under it. But based on the solution in the book and some of the online solutions, I believe I am misunderstanding the problem and this is not correct, so I was hoping to get some assistance. Can any of you explain why the solution to this problem needs to look for each possible combination of the boxes and not just generate an ordered list of the boxes?

Thanks!

Comment: There is only one "tallest" stack which meets the requirements but there could be multiple combinations which satisfy the base constraints while being shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the situation in which there are only three boxes which are (in WxDxH) 1x7x2, 1x6x2 and 7x1x5. There is no strict ordering of these boxes as neither of the first two can fit on the third. Yet the correct solution is the third box by itself (5 > 2+2). If I understand your algorithm, it won't cope with this situation. A solution to the problem needs to support multiple stacks and adding each box to all the stacks it can be included on.

Comment: Ah. I think I understand now. I did not understand the original premise of the problem correctly. In your example, 1x7x2 and 7x1x5 are incompatible to stack on one another in either order because neither is completely greater than the other (1 < 7, 7 > 1, 2 < 5). While in my algorithm, I am assuming if one box is not completely greater than another, than it can simply go on top of that box, which is an incorrect assumption. In other words, in your example I was assuming the max height would always be 2 + 2 + 5 and we simply wanted to calculate the order of the boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution doesn't seem to be right. It always report list containing all boxes in some order. If you have 3 boxes [w10, h10, d10], [w5, h5, d5], [w1, h1, d20] then only first two form tallest stack.

If you try to find recursive solution you'll realize that it takes exponential time. Dynamic programming is best solution here. It takes only quadratic time.

The idea is not so hard. You just make oriented graph with boxes in vertices and add edges between two vertices only if box in target vertex could be put on top of box in source vertex. Weight of each vertex is height of box in it. Then best stack corresponds to path in this graph with maximum sum of weights of vertices. Key thing here is visited vertices. All vertices should have "not yet visited" mark at the beginning. Second necessary field in each vertex is aggregated best height of stack ending with a box from this vertex. Third property is back reference to best previous vertex. Algorithm start from vertices which don't have incoming edges. You just use their heights as best ones and mark them as visited. On each next step you can visit only vertices which have all incoming edges with visited source vertices. When you visit some vertex you pick best incoming edge (with highest aggregated height). You add height of current vertex to aggregated height and store in this vertex. Also you store back reference from this vertex to previous vertex where the best path came from. Finally you should choose best vertex from set of vertices not having outgoing edges. Going back from best final vertex along back reference you reconstruct best path giving you best stack.

Comment: Thanks, I believe I understand where my misunderstanding is coming from now. Your solution is a different approach than the one in the book so I appreciate you detailing it up so I can take a look at another approach to this problem.